# VBA - How to add an absolute sum row at the end of the range in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet where I want to add an Absolute Sum Row at the end of a range as shown in the Image.

[image]

I am trying to achieve this by writing a macro. I have attached my code in which I have tried to add the Absolute Sum Row at the end of the range.

```
MAX = 1502
Src = 0
N = 0
Freq = 0.05
Freqmax = 1

Op = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")

For Freq = 0.05 To Freqmax Step 0.01

K = 0.5 * R * Sin(WorksheetFunction.Pi * Freq)

C1 = 0.5 * (1 - K) / (1 + K)
C2 = (0.5 + C1) * Cos(WorksheetFunction.Pi * Freq)
C3 = (0.5 + C1 - C2) * 0.25

ma0 = 2 * C3
ma1 = 2 * 2 * C3
ma2 = 2 * C3
mb1 = 2 * (-C2)
mb2 = 2 * C1

For Src = 0 To MAX Step 1

    Inp = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)

    Op = ma0 * Inp + ma1 * mx1 + ma2 * mx2 - mb1 * my1 - mb2 * my2
    mx2 = mx1
    mx1 = Inp
    my2 = my1
    my1 = Op

    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) = Op
    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src) = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) - ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)

Next

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src).End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "M").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:M" & LastRow & ")"

ActiveSheet.Columns("L:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Next
```

My code works in a way where I am incrementing frequency at the end of the loop and moving the calculations to the right so that I can insert values for next frequency value.

So what I am trying to do is to calculate the Absolute Sum for one range.

But I am encountering an error "Application-defined or object-defined error" in this line of the code.

```
Cells(LastRow + 2, "M").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:M" & LastRow & ")"
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the right way to do this?

Comment: replace your "m" with the column number?

Comment: `Cells(LastRow + 2, "2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:2" & LastRow & ")"` this way?

Comment: This way ... `ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 2, 13).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:2" & LastRow & ")"`, but notice it was a question ... try it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still encountering the same error.

Comment: I see you say NEXT, but do you really need to say NEXT SRC and NEXT Freq?  I also do not see what MAX is defined as not that it should make a difference.  Instead of saying active sheet you may want to define which sheet, then again you may not just food for thought.   I also dont believe you need to say STEP 1, I believe it steps by 1 by default, you only need step if you are doing something different.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I have edited the code and moved those two lines of code out of the SRC for-loop. So that It calculates the absolute value for each SRC for every frequency. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks a lot @ForwardEd for the suggestions and help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @OldUgly for the suggestions and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing below M2 when you try to determine the **lastRow** in this code line.

```
lastRow = .Range("M" & 2 + src).End(xlDown).Row
```

That means that **lastRow** is going to be 1048576 (the number of rows on the worksheet). When you try to add **2** to that number in the next line of code (in 2 places),

```
.Cells(lastRow + 2, "M").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:M" & lastRow & ")"
```

... you are trying to a) work with a cell that is two rows below the bottom of the worksheet and b) trying to reference a cell that is two rows off the worksheet in a formula.

You can fix this by looking from the bottom up.

```
lastRow = .Range("M" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

However, I question whether that is where the column subtotal belongs. A better place may be referenced by moving those two lines of code outside the inner loop and just before inserting the new columns.

```
    Next src

    lastRow = .Range("M" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(lastRow + 2, "M").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:M" & lastRow & "))"
    .Columns("L:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next freq
```

**addendum:** The [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) was missing a closing bracket.

Comment: damn those missing brackets!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Jeeped. It works as expected. Perfect! :)